# Renderscript Video Sync Issues on Motorola Xoom?

Tags: android, renderscript, xoom

I've been messing around with Renderscript using a Motorola Xoom. Everything works ok but there are rendering issues. I'm not sure if it's specific to the Xoom or not.

You can see the problem when running the Balls sample application. When the larger balls are at rest they look like white spots with a halo. However, when the larger balls move the halo appears to lag slightly behind the ball.

However, in this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQ5NumRfHN4) the balls render properly. The halo remains properly in place as the ball moves.

So something isn't right on the Xoom. I think it's a video sync issue.

I tried adding a call to rsgAllocationSyncAll() but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are simply noticing the effect of the display's refresh rate. The video you are linking to was recorded from a Xoom using HDMI output. Renderscript, just like OpenGL and everything else on Android, is vsync'd by default.

Comment: Ok I see. Thanks so much for the response. So basically the Xoom display sucks big time. Bummer...

Comment: After further investigation it looks like it's defective. I'm gonna exchange it. Thanks!